# Vector space basis on R+

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, addition and scalar multiplication in the set $\mathbb{R}^{+}$  is defined as $a\otimes b := a\cdot b$ and $k\circ a=a^{k}$. How should I find $\dim(V)$ and a basis or what's the idea to solve this question? As I understand, it should be a little more tricky question, but it was a midterm exam practice question.

Comment: As it stands this question is worded a little confusingly. Please avoid using logical symbols in the middle of a sentence, I mistook $\wedge$ for a wedge product. Also, when defining new operations, use $:=$ to aid in distinguishing the term being defined from the definition, i.e. $a\otimes b := ab$. Also, $\otimes$ is an unusual choice of symbol for the addition operation of a vector space, but of course this choice is ultimately up to you. :)

Comment: Hint. Can you generate every $b\in\mathbb R^+=(0,\infty)$ by $b=a^k$ for some fixed $a$ ? If yes, what is a basis of that vector space?

Answer (score 2):

The dimension is $1$; the zero element of the abelian group $({\bf R}^+, \times)$ is $1$; any nonzero element e.g. $10$ will generate the vector space.

For $x \in {\bf R}$ such that $x > 0$, if we put $k = \log_{10} x$ we have $x = k \circ 10$.